# css - select all ul elements except ul elements that are in a div with a specific class?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a global `ul` styles like below in my `global.scss` file:

```scss
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I need some way to manipulate this that not select `ul`'s in a specific div with a class `jodit-wrapper` if I do something like below it doesn't work:

```scss
ul:not(.jodit-wrapper) {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

what is the correct way for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it with this:

```
ul:not(.jodit-wrapper ul) {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It wont work. please remove your answer

Comment: actually it does :)

Comment: I got you wrong then :)+

Comment: Good answers include an explanation of why the code works.

Answer (score 1):

The `jodit-wrapper` class is for the parent `div` of the `ul`? if yes you need something like this:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.jodit-wrapper ul {
  list-style: inside;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jodit-wrapper"> 
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
<div>
   <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If the `jodit-wrapper` class is for the `ul` then your code works.

Answer (score 0):

We need to not select the div that has the class jodit-wrapper.

```css
/* do not select uls in any div which has a class jodit-wrapper */

div:not(.jodit-wrapper) ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="jodit-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>I should have default list style</li>
    <ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>I should not have a list style</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```